# Puppet relationships with nested functions

Tags: puppet, apt

I use the official Puppet apt module to add [this Java launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) and to install Oracle Java 8.

```
  apt::ppa{ 'ppa:webupd8team/java': }

  package {
      "oracle-java8-installer":
        ensure => 'installed',
  }
```

When the apt module adds the launchpad it notifies another manifest to run 'apt-get update'.

apt/manifests/ppa.pp

```
exec { "add-apt-repository-${name}":
  environment => $_proxy_env,
  command     => "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository ${options} ${name}",
  unless      => "/usr/bin/test -s ${::apt::sources_list_d}/${sources_list_d_filename}",
  user        => 'root',
  logoutput   => 'on_failure',
  notify      => Exec['apt::update::apt_update'],
  require     => $_require,
}
```

The problem is that I can't get make sure that the source update is run before the install begins.

Using 'require' or 'before' the update is run **after** the install (add source -> install Java -> apt-get update), subscribe returns a dependency cycle and using no relationships it installs before updating my sources.

What's the solution?

Using Frank's code:

```
apt::ppa{ 'ppa:webupd8team/java': }

package {
          "oracle-java8-installer":
                ensure => 'installed',
                require => Apt::Ppa['ppa:webupd8team/java'],
}
```

I get this error message:

> ==> xxx: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[xxx]/Apt::Ppa[ppa:webupd8team/java]/Exec[add-apt-repository-ppa:webupd8team/java]/returns:
>   executed successfully
>
> ==> xxx: Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install oracle-java8-installer'
>   returned 100: Reading package lists...
>
> ==> xxx: Building dependency tree...
>
> ==> xxx: Reading state information...
>
> ==> xxx: E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
>
> ==> xxx: Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[xxx]/Package[oracle-java8-installer]/ensure:
>   change from purged to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get
>   -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install oracle-java8-installer' returned 100: Reading package lists...
>
> ==> xxx: Building dependency tree...
>
> ==> xxx: Reading state information...
>
> ==> xxx: E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
>
> ==> xxx: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Dependency Package[oracle-java8-installer] has failures: true
>
> ==> xxx: Warning: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Skipping because of failed dependencies
>
> ==> xxx: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events

Using this:

```
package {
          "oracle-java8-installer":
                ensure => 'installed',
                require => Exec['apt::update::apt_update'],
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Failed to apply catalog: Could not find dependency Exec[apt::update::apt_update] for Package[oracle-java8-installer]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findings are confusing. `require` should really get you there.

```
package {
  "oracle-java8-installer":
    ensure  => 'installed',
    require => Apt::Ppa['ppa:webupd8team/java'],
}
```

Comment: Yes that's what I tried. The result was that the source was added, the Java installation failed (package not found) and then the update was run.

Comment: The reason is likely that the udpate `exec` is included from yet another class, which is not targeted by the `require`. What's the result with `require => Exec['apt::update::apt_update']` in the `package` resource?

Comment: I tried it with your solution and added the error message to the original post.

Comment: @Pulz This is weird because your original snippet alleges to `notify` just that resource. Apparently, it should just be `require => Exec[apt_update]`.

Comment: It seems to work in the first try, I'll stay in touch in case other nodes have errors. Thanks a lot!